# Understand number validation in pyqt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt6

I'm not sure how to understand [QIntValidator()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qintvalidator.html) and [QDoubleValidator()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdoublevalidator.html). I'm implementing it like:

```
    Int_validator = QIntValidator()
    self.lineedit_tube = QLineEdit(self)
    self.lineedit_tube.setValidator(Int_validator)
```

Now I realized that when I enter a `QlineEdit()` within a GUI and move with the mouse cursor away from it, that the decimal numbers change, e.g. from `0.05` to `5E+00`, or `18.25` to `1,825E+03`.
When I use `,` instead of `.` it doesn't change but as far as I see a , is not a number but a vector? At least the console provides as output:

```
10,0e+0
Out[12]: (10, 0.0)

10.0e+0
Out[13]: 10.0
```

I also thought it could be due to `QIntValidator()` so I replaced it with `QDoubleValidator()` but the behavior remains. Next, I also thought it could be due to a country property, so I used

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8')
```

but it's still the same behavior. How do I solve this and/or why does this happen?

Comment: It *is* the locale. Don't confuse programming notation (which always uses the *point* for decimals) from the Ui representation, which follows the system locale, and is correct (if you're in Germany, like most European countries, the standard is the decimal comma).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! What exactly do I have to change then or to check what is set?

Comment: Ah, I guess I understood it now. Means, the values within the GUI should be separated by comma because the GUI follows my local system. But when I set the locale explicitly e.g. to Germany, then values like 2,5E-02 should be 0.025 and not (2, 0.05), or? Whatever this representation means, anyway.. Well, however, figured out that everything works fine when I replace the dot with a comma.

Comment: With `2,5E-02` are you referring to the Python conversion?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention that: I'm using Spyder and this the output from its console.

Comment: Output if *what*? Printing from the program? Typing in the interactive shell?